# f and b symbol in jump instructions in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

the question is to write assembly program to calculate n!. n is in rdi, the result should be in rdx:rax. If the result can not be written in rdx:rax, the maximal number that fit in rdx:rax should be returned.
In the link below is the correct answer. I only have a small question: why "ja 3f" and not simply "ja 3" in line 3, and why "ja 1b" in line 17 ? What is the meaning of "f" and "b" here?

```
factorial:
    cmp rdi, 34
    ja 3f
    xor edx, edx // Result stored in rdx:rax
    mov eax, 1
    cmp edi, 1
    jbe 2f    
1:  // Compute rdx:rax = rdx:rax * rdi
    // New rdx: rdx*rdi + (rax*rdi >> 64)
    // New rax: rax*rdi
    mov rcx, rdi
    imul rcx, rdx // First part of new rdx
    mul rdi // New rax + second part of new rdx
    sub edi, 1
    add rdx, rcx // New rdx
    cmp edi, 1

    ja 1b // Break loop if edi <= 1
2:  ret

3:  mov rax, -1
    mov rdx, -1
    ret
```

Comment: `b` is for the label backward and `f` is forward

Comment: @MichaelPetch, could you share some documentation or other useful link(s) to understand what this actually means and when it should be used, because I can't find anything that explains this and never met it before...

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica : that has now been resolved

Answer (score 3):

`1:`, `2:`, and so on, are "local labels" in GNU assembler syntax, and `f` and `b` tell the assembler where to go look for these labels.

Within a source file there can be many labels whose name is the same single digit.  `3f` means the next label `3:` after the current line, `3b` means the nearest one before that.

Such labels are very useful because if you want to go just a handful of lines back or forward you don't have to think of a unique name each time, and the code is suitable to copy+paste into other files without thinking about what names may already be used.  If you are going much further than that you should probably think of a meaningful name to make it easier to read.

See the [GNU as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1) for more details.